# SVG background covers button color in CSS

Tags: css, svg

I have an svg image that I would like to be contained inside of a white button, however, inserting it into the background in CSS covers the white color of the button completely. How does one avoid this in CSS?

Button with svg background:

```
#rack-button {
    position: absolute;
    background: url('simple_rack.svg') no-repeat top left;
    background-size: contain;
    display: inline-block;
    width:  35px;
    height: 35px;
    left: 10%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color:#fff;
}
```

[image]

Button without svg background:

```
#rack-button {
    position: absolute;
    width:  35px;
    height: 35px;
    left: 10%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color:#fff;
}
```

[image]

Comment: change color with background-color

Comment: Does the SVG have a background color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial button CSS has no `background-color` stated so this must be stated *somewhere else* in your CSS.

```
#rack-button {
  position: absolute;
  width:  35px;
  height: 35px;
  left: 10%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color:#fff;
}
```

When you added the image background you **overrode** the original background color and substituted a *transparent* image, so the `body` background shows through

```
#rack-button {
  position: absolute;
   background: url('simple_rack.svg') no-repeat top left;
   background-size: contain;
   display: inline-block;
  width:  35px;
  height: 35px;
  left: 10%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color:#fff;
}
```

You just need to add the background color back

```
#rack-button {
   background: white url('simple_rack.svg') no-repeat top left;
}
```

or

```
#rack-button {
   background: url('simple_rack.svg') no-repeat top left;
   background-color:white;
}
```